# Why is F1 measure effective for evaluating multiclass classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification

I was looking for a good error metric for multiclass classifiers, and many people say that F1 measure is usually used.
But given that predictions of multiclass classifiers are one-hot vectors, doesn't it mean there are no true positives when the prediction is wrong?
What i mean is:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdFkM.png)

when the prediction is correct, every element is true negatives except for the single '1'. So the precision here is just 1.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H0j1.png)

And when the prediction is incorrect, there is no true positives. So the precision is 0.

I would understand that F1 is a powerful metric method when it comes to multilabel classifications, since there can be more than one 1's in the vector, but applying F1 on multiclass classification seems a bit weird to me. Isn't it same with just accuracy?
Or does it mean that F1 score **per class** should be used?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest giving a look on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score#cite_note-11), in particular the section "Extension to multi-class classification".

A good explanation about how to apply F1 to multiclass classifiers is found on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/python-machine-learning/multi-class-evaluation-1ugJR).